# VB6 RSS Example?

Tags: vb6, rss

i need an example - how to parse RSS feeds by under Visual Basic 6... help please)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using [ChilkatRSS](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatRssRef.html).

```
Dim r As New ChilkatRSS

' Get the searchenginewatch.com feed
success = r.DownloadRss("http://feeds.searchenginewatch.com/sew")
If (success = 0) Then
    MsgBox "Failed to download RSS feed"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Get the first channel
Dim channel As ChilkatRSS
Set channel = r.GetChannel(0)

Dim item As ChilkatRSS

nItems = channel.NumItems
For i = 0 To nItems - 1
    Set item = channel.GetItem(i)
    List1.AddItem item.GetString("title")
Next
```

Comment: This answer isn't much help right now. You must have referenced a special library. You need to tell us which one it was.

Comment: It looked like the example was using a library called ChilkatRSS. I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One place to begin might be [Introducing the Windows RSS Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686418%28VS.85%29.aspx).

However I haven't seen any useful examples.